# Problem with finding StripesResources.properties in classpath

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, stripes

I'm trying to work with Messages in Stripes, a feature present in the StripesReesources.properties file, which, according to most tutorials and my book, should be placed under the src folder so in the main classpath.
Additionally, since it did not work, i placed it also in a folder caller "res", as subfolder of `WEB-INF`, nothing, Tomcat throws a JasperException:

> Could not find the error message resource bundle needed by Stripes. This almost certainly means that a properties file called 'StripesResources.properties' could not be found in the classpath

I use `Tomcat 6`, `JDK 6`, a good IDE, i dont think is the Ides issue as it wont work also on another ide.
Somewhere i have read "but i cant find this webpage anymore" that also this feature needs to be explicitly declared in the web.xml, but even on the official StripesFramework website i cant see anything regarding about it, so there should not be any configuration in web.xml for `StripesResurces.properties`
Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It should be there in default package directly under the src. and upon build it should go to `WEB-INF/classes` so directly under class path.

[**Update**](http://www.mail-archive.com/stripes-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03112.html)

It was pretty interesting issue. I found the solution from [Freedy's post](http://www.mail-archive.com/stripes-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03112.html) and here you go

You need to configure your web.xml to tell stripe from where to look for resource

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter
  </filter-class>
  <!-- other init params...-->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>
      LocalizationBundleFactory.FieldNameBundle
    </param-name>
    <param-value>com/stripesTest/properties/StripesResources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>
      LocalizationBundleFactory.ErrorMessageBundle
    </param-name>
    <param-value>com/stripesTest/properties/StripesResources</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

If you also want to use this resource bundle for JSTL  tags, you
also need to add this at the top of the WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
  </param-name>
  <param-value>com/stripesTest/properties/StripesResources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thats exactly where it is, Tomcat wont find it,

Comment: where have you put your `stripes.jar`?

Comment: please check is there any stripe lib under  tomcat shared/libs ?

Comment: No Jigar, under tomcat>lib there are no Stripes lib